# Can we use precision and recall in regression?

Tags: regression, precision-recall

Precision is the ratio of true positive to all the positive results whereas recall is the ratio of true positives to all relevant results. As we know that precision and recall are classification metrics.

Lets say we have a regression problem and after the removal of outliers I found that the range of the most of the target variables is between 30-35 and 35-40. Lets say 150 datapoints have target values in the range of 30-35 and 50 datapoints have target values in the range 35-40

So ,for a feature variable whose target variable falls in the range of 30-35, if my model predicts any real value (eg. 33.4, 31.9 etc.) in the range of 30 to 35, i am considering it a **true positive** and if it predicts anything outside the range then I am considering it **false positive**. Same for 35-40 group. By doing that, I can calculate precision and recall in this case.

So would it be okay to use precision and recall as a performance metric like this ?

P.S. My question might sound a little stupid, but please clarify me before downvoting it.

Comment: I couldn't quite get your positive definition.

Comment: @gunes Hey i am sorry if i failed in making it clear.  suppose the original values were 30.6, 32 , 33.6, and 34. So i know that these 4 values are falling in range of 30 - 35. If my model predicts 32.5, 34.3, 34.9 and 35.7 , so i among these i got 3 values which were in the range of 30-35 and 1 is out of the range. So I am considering those 3 values as "positive" and rest of the one as "negative"